# Allowing communication through firewall

Tags: networking, security, firewall, cisco, file-sharing

I have just recently been hired at a web development company right out of college. I am currently struggling with a task and was hoping to get some help with operating a firewall.

I currently have 2 IIS servers and 2 SQL servers on the same domain. However, there is a Cisco ASDM firewall sitting between the IIS and the SQL servers. I have created a batch job on the IIS server to zip up and send files over to the SQL server. (For backup purposes). However I received the following message when trying to manually transmit files via explore between the servers...

"This usually means that a firewall is running somewhere between the two computers and is blocking "File and printer sharing (SMB)" If you have access to this firewall then configure the firewall to allow connections through TCP port 445.

Being new at networking and especially with Firewalls, how do I go about setting up this rule within my firewall ASDM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have admin access to the ASDM it's dead easy. Your best bet is to read the **[Cisco docs here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa71/configuration/guide/filter.html)** first as you will want to understand what you are doing before you touch it - messing this up could break all comms through that firewall!

Also, going one level further up - check you really want to allow file and printer sharing between these two network segments - from a security perspective, the firewall is doing what it is supposed to at the moment, blocking risks - so you will be raising the level of risk (probably only incrementally, but check)

More generally - if there is an IT team or IT Security team, make the request to open 445 on that firewall between the 4 servers, giving reasons, and let them deal with it - as I mentioned: **you could cause major problems if you have not configured a firewall before!**

Answer (score 0):

This would be a NAT policy. You need a original address and original port, then a destination address and destination port. The starting address would be your two extneral IIS servers on your WAN side using port 445. From there you would tell it which server you want it to go to and the original port (445).

You can find more specific info [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa72/asdm52/user/guide/nat.html)